# Unable to save item

Tags: web8

we are unable to save old components post upgrade from sdl tridion 2013 sp1 hr1 to sdl web 8. we are getting below error.

```
(80040356) Unable to save item
Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
```

[image]
Note: we are not facing for new components.

Could you please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Are you seeing this in all browsers or only a particular browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue with Chrome 49, you need to install the hotfix "CME_8.1.0.1673" from SDL. The hotfix is available [HERE](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Web_8/index.aspx)(login required). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Shiva for your inputs,we are using Chrome 55 version and moreover we have already installed above hotfix in our environment.

Comment: If you are seeing this error only on Chrome 55, I would suggest that you raise a ticket with SDL support.

Comment: It is not related to browser issue and it is a product issue. SDL team is trying to provide hotfix.